# VBA Images lost when inserting one word document into another

Tags: image, vba, ms-word, office-automation

I am producing reports that are comprised of 4 chapters, an introduction chapter and 3 dynamically created chapters. The 3 dynamic chapters are produced separately, and then inserted after the introduction chapter and saved as a single unit. The three dynamic chapters are working fine and look as they should, and other than the missing images the combined version looks as it should as well.

One of the dynamic chapters uses the InsertFile method to bring in 6 images that are saved as RTF files. I can't change the format of the incoming images, and since they are not technically images I have to insert them as text. This does not present an issue when the chapter is by itself, as they appear as they should. However, when the chapters are combined, these images are lost. I am also combining the 4 documents (introduction + 3 dynamic chapters) using the InsertFile method.

So far I've confirmed that if I manually insert the problematic dynamic chapter into a blank document it also loses the images. The chapters are saved to a local drive. I have also confirmed that if I move the chapter file to a network drive, it seems to import fine (however, that's not an option).

Does this problem sound familiar to anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Does the account the application is running under have the necessary permissions?

I faced [a similar situation with Excel Interop.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852411/why-would-the-excel-interop-remove-an-image-after-processing-a-file) The culprit was the **Local Service** account not having enough permissions. I changed it to run under **Local System** and the images persisted.

Comment: Thanks. This sounds like it might be the problem, but I'm not sure exactly how to change it to run under Local System. I opened up the services.msc window, but I'm not sure which "service" to select. I don't see anything like Microsoft Word or Office, other than Microsoft Office Diagnostics. What do you change for Excel? Thanks again.

Comment: I changed the actual service -- that was my application that called Office. Are you running from the desktop or IDE under your own account?

Comment: I'm running from the desktop under a shared administrator account.